# How to Crop and download image from a url in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried using various libraries like [image_crop](https://pub.dev/packages/image_crop) and [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) . But they only let you crop local images but I want to Crop an online image and store the cropped image. What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Using Flutter `cached_network_image` or `flutter_cache_manager` (The cached network images stores and retrieves files using the flutter_cache_manager) you can get the file from the network.

```
var imageFile =
        await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile('https://your_network_image_url');
```

Then you can send this file to `image_cropper` to crop it.

```
Future<Null> _cropImage(File imageFile) async {
    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: imageFile.path,
      ratioX: 1.0,
      ratioY: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 512,
      maxHeight: 512,
    );
}
```